# React ES6 class method does not render into html table but outside it. Why?

Tags: reactjs, html-table

I want to understand ES6 and are using HTML table to render external React elements. Having trouble rendering this ES6 class into a html table.

I've tried rendering ES6 object from inside the class by returning a string to a HTML table which didn't render so now I render it externally to the class which renders to the bottom outside the table. I am using external CSS for the table and none of the other rendered elements are affected and are rendering to thier cells.

React.js

```
//PROBLEM: To create an igor skate from an inline skate model.
//START
//CREATE Class Roller_Blades.
    //CONSTRTUCT property Name "Inline Skate" 

    //RETURN SkateType "I am a "  Name " designed for mass production."
//END CLASS
class InlineSkate {
    constructor(name) {
      this.brand = name;
    }

    present() {
      return  "I am a " + this.brand + " designed for mass production."
    }
  }


//This string outside the class will output 'K2 Skate' back into
// InlineSkate.CreateRollerBlade().  
var skate = new InlineSkate('K2 Skate');
document.write(skate.present());
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(InlineSkate, null), document.getElementById('esSixClassExample'));
```

HTML

```
<body>

    <!--Output-->
    <table ID="DoubleBorderedTable">
      <tbody>
      <tr>       
        <th>ES6 Class Example</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div id="hello-example"></div></td>
        <td><div id="clock-example"></div></td>   
        <td><div id="es6ClassExample"></div></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

    <!-- Load React. -->
    <!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with
    production.min.js". -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>    
    <!-- Load our React components.-->
    <script src="scripts/simple_component.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/Clock.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ESSixClassExample.js"></script>
  </body>
```

The class function "present" that returns a string ends up rendering outside and below the table and not in the desired last cell of the last row of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(InlineSkate, null), document.getElementById('esSixClassExample'))

This is doing nothing. I'd be willing to bet that if you opened your console you'd see an error that says something like, "Cannot call a class as a function".

What's printing the string outside the table are these two lines,

> var skate = new InlineSkate('K2 Skate');
>
> document.write(skate.present());

As it is you aren't really using React at all. The first argument of `ReactDOM.render()` should be either a function component, a class component, or a string designating the type of element to be created.

In order to get the output you want without changing what you're doing so much, you'd need to do something like this,

```
var skate = new InlineSkate("K2 Skate");
ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement("span", { children: skate.present() }),
  document.getElementById("esSixClassExample")
);
```

What that will do is create a `span` element, stick it inside your `esSixClassExample` div, and then run your present function to generate your text and assigning the text node as a child of the span.

This is pretty irregular though, and unless you're just doing this for learning purposes or as part of a class or something, you really ought to be using React components (because why even bother with React otherwise.)

Here is a class component example.

```
class InlineSkate extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return React.createElement(React.Fragment, null, "I am a ", this.props.brand, " designed for mass production.");
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(InlineSkate, {
  brand: "K2 Skate"
}), document.getElementById('classComponent'));
```

And here is a function component example.

```
function InlineSkate({ brand }) {
  return React.createElement(React.Fragment, null, "I am a ", brand, " designed for mass production.");
}

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(InlineSkate, {
  brand: "K2 Skate"
}), document.getElementById('functionComponent'));
```

Comment: Yes I'm using this completely for self learning purposes for ES6 which is vital to understand React.  Thanks for your answer but you're using JSX. That's not working because I'm using a html page to render external React code pages. You're probably expecting me to use the Create React App instead which I realize I should have done.

Comment: The first half of my answer is where I explain where you went wrong, and in that area I hadn't used any JSX. Either way, I've edited my response so that it no longer uses any JSX.